# Inputting DatePicker in TextField problems

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm trying to let the user pick a date and let it display in a text field. I've found so many answers online but none of them seem to work. I don't if they are outdated. I'm getting an error on "datePickerView.addTarget" in the selector part. When I run the app, I tap on the text field and the keyboard appears which is what I want. But the app crashes as soon as I change the date.

Any help would be really appreciated!

```
@IBAction func dateFieldEditing(sender: UITextField) {

    let datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date

    sender.inputView = datePickerView

    datePickerView.addTarget(self, action:Selector("handleDatePicker"),forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)

}


func handleDatePicker (sender: UIDatePicker){

    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .LongStyle
    dateField.text = formatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
}
```

Comment: You syntax is a little dated. Your code is mostly fine, but it should be `datePickerView.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.handleDatePicker),forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)` That is `#selector(….)` Not sure why the compiler doesn't complain.

Comment: @beyowulf Perfect!! It worked. Thanks A LOT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works, assuming that you have a UITextField and UIDatePicker bound as IBOutlets via Interface Builder. Setting sender.inputView was unnecessary.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker?
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField?

    func handleDatePicker (sender: UIDatePicker) {
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .LongStyle
        textField!.text = formatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.datePicker!.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
        datePicker!.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleDatePicker(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }
}
```