# text field with date picker crashes on date changed swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, datepicker, textfield

I am having trouble with a text field that I am setting up. The goal is instead of the keyboard, I want it to have slide wheels to indicate a time. So inside `viewDidLoad()` I put:

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerValueChanged"), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
textField.inputView = datePicker
```

And within the ViewController() I put:

```
@objc func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let DatePickerView: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
    textField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: DatePickerView.date)
}
```

Now this looks great for opening the text field, the scroll bars for time pop right up, and look great (Woot!). But when I change the time, the application crashes (NSException). I understand that this usually occurs when a connection is not properly set up, but I can not figure out what connection as the `Selector` for `textField` should trigger function `datePickerValueChanged`. The scene loads fine, it is just when I change the date that I get NSException.

I also tried with/without `@objc` function label

I found solutions to three other similar questions, but they did not seem to work for me (maybe outdated). Links:

[UIDatePicker crashing application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635311/uidatepicker-crashing-application)

[Inputting DatePicker in TextField problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38214908/inputting-datepicker-in-textfield-problems/38215029)

[UITextField with DatePicker crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927969/uitextfield-with-datepicker-crashes)

Any thoughts/ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: change `Selector("datePickerValueChanged")` to `#selector(datePickerValueChanged)` and change `DatePickerView.date` to `sender.date` and delete this code `let DatePickerView: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the crash change your selector from

```
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerValueChanged"), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
```

to

```
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(datePickerValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
```

and in your method:

```
@objc func datePickerValueChanged(_ sender: UIDatePicker) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm a" // or "HH:mm"
    textField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: sender.date)
}
```